# macro: how to browse excel file and read data

Tags: excel, file, vba

I am writing a macro script in 3 steps:

read an excel file by browse - transfer to xml format - export xml file to certain path by browse. 
I know how to export by browse alrady.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "choose the path you want to export the xml file", 0, 0)
```

but this one is browseforfolder.

How to browse for file? if I want to import excel data by browse?

thx

Comment: You have not accepeted an answer to any of your prior questions. You are more likely to get assistance if you are viewed as engaging fully with the people helping you.

Comment: excuse me, I log SO about 3 weeks. every time i just click "yes" for "is it useful for you?" but how to show I accept the answer?

Comment: Just click the gray check-mark next to the answer that solved your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the "open file" dialog, I use the following:

```
FileOpenName = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All files (*.*), *.*")
```

Then you're going to need following to open the files the

```
Open FileOpenName For (Binary|Write) as #1
   'Do writing operations here
Close #1
```

Comment: thx. could u explain further if the script want to use several worksheets' data from that FileOpenName. I do not understand very much about that Open... Close #1.